# How to use ruby win32ole to set Microsoft Exchange proxy settings?

Tags: ruby, proxy, settings, exchange-server, win32ole

using Outlook to access my work Exchange inbox via a HTTPS proxy used to be very straightforward until my employer changed the principal name I have to use. Mysteriously, in the background, the principal name gets reset to the old value. Now pretty much every time I log in, and often several times in a login session, I have to reconfigure the principal name to the new value in order to use VPN-less Outlook. Reconfiguring the HTTPS proxy principal name requires ten mouse clicks to get to the right text field (Control Panel -> mail, etc), then, once I've changed it, seven further mouse clicks to save it. It really winds me up that my employer can't find a solution to this.

I would love to be able to script this. Does anybody know (a) if it is possible and (b) how to access the Exchange proxy settings via ruby's win32ole? I've googled and googled but nobody else appears to have done this.

Kind regards,
Rob

Answer (score 0):

through the registry maybe? (win32/registry.rb)